# Prevent update check for specific theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, updates

I'm working on a custom theme that lives in `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/custom/`. It's for internal use, so it doesn't matter if there's a theme with the same name on the wordpress site.

But wordpress performs an update check, finds a theme with the same name, which has a newer version number, and so asks me to upgrade.

Is there a way to suppress this behavior without renaming my theme and without fiddling with version numbers? I don't want the check to be performed at all.

(BTW `define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true)` doesn't help.)

Comment: Did you find a way to disable the update check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can disable auto update by adding this line of code in your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

OR Disable automatic WordPress theme updates by adding the following filters in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks. But from what I've read `define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true)` disables ALL updates, and even that doesn't help.

Comment: Also, I only want to disable the check for **this** theme - is that possible?

Comment: Try add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' ); for theme

Comment: In [the official docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/configuring-automatic-background-updates/#constant-to-disable-all-updates) it says that the way I've done it should disable ALL checks. But that isn't what I've observed. The way you've proposed is a subset. So surely this is a hack?

Comment: You can also make your theme version like in style.css. Version: 9.9.9

Comment: I think maybe this is a bug, or maybe it cannot be done :(

Comment: Yes that's also a hack, and also performs a check - I mentioned that I want to avoid the version number trick and do something more robust. Thanks for your assistance though. Upvoted!

Comment: For perticular theme try below code may it will help

function disable_theme_update_notification( $value ) {
    if ( isset( $value ) && is_object( $value ) ) {
        unset( $value->response['custom'] );
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_themes', 'disable_theme_update_notification' );